# Share Nuget Package with different Azure DevOps Server over Upstream

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget, azure-artifacts

Summary:

- I am trying to get an Azure Artifact (NuGet Package) synchronized between two DevOps Projects using Feeds
- When both Projects belong to the same DevOps tenant i have no problems
- When i try to synchronize between two different tenants i get an error.

=> Is this doable in general or impossible?

I have the following setup:

Org A

- User A
- DevOps Server A (Needs external NuGet Package)
- Feed A

Org B

- User B
- DevOps Server B
- Feed B (external NuGet Package)

Is it possible to connect the feed of Org B to Org A with Azure custom Upstreams (Add Upstream -> Azure Artifacts feed in another organization -> azure-feed://OrgB/ProjectB/FeedB@Local -> NuGet -> Save)

If i want to save the Upstream Resources I always get the following error message:
`The source at 'azure-feed://OrgB/ProjectB/FeedB@Local' cannot be configured as an upstream because it does not exist or you do not have permissions to it.`

I tried giving access to User A to Org B but it does not work. Is this even possible (in a technical sense)?
If not, what is the best way to share a NuGet Package with a different Organisation (different Azure DevOps Server)? I do not want to be dependent on a server in Org B. Best case is the NuGet Package is mirrored in Org A. In the unlikely event that the server or Azure DevOps from Org B is down, the build in Org A still works.

1. I invited User A to DevOps Server B. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=azure-devops)
2. Added User A to Feed B (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add upstream source` needs to be in the same Azure Active Directory.
Besides , you  use service connection->nuget->External Azure Server to share Nuget Package.

[image]

Comment: Org A and Org B use different Azure Active Directories. The solution was to push the NuGet Package from Org B to Org A through an azure pipeline using a NuGet Service Connection.